# @fullcalendar/react header options as drop down navigation

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I have to put @fullcalendar/react header options(i.e Day view, Week view, and Monthly view) with some custom options in a drop-down menu. After selecting one of these options, it'll go to a particular one. How can we customize this? Does anyone have an idea about how to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all capture fullCalendar component and put it in a ref like:

```js
  const calendarRef = React.useRef();

   <FullCalendar
        ref={calendarRef}
        // rest of your props goes here...
   />
```

Then create a state to hold the preferred view and pass it, its state setter, and an array of labels and values for views to the drop-down component:

```js
  const [showBy, setShowBy] = React.useState("dayGridMonth");


  const choices = [
{
  label: "Day",
  value: "timeGridDay",
},
{
  label: "Week",
  value: "timeGridWeek",
},
{
  label: "Month",
  value: "dayGridMonth",
},
  ];

<CustomDropDown
   label="View"
   choices={choices}
   action={setShowBy}
   initialValue={showBy}
   class_name="viewSelector"
 />
```

**CustomDropDown** component (mine uses MUI Select component):

```js
export default function CustomDropDown({
  label,
  choices,
  action,
  initialValue,
  class_name,
}) {
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    action(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl id={class_name}>
      <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-helper-label">{label}</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-helper-label"
        id="demo-simple-select-helper"
        value={initialValue}
        label={`${label}`}
        onChange={handleChange}
        defaultValue=""
        placeholder={label}
      >
        {choices.map((element) => {
          return (
            <MenuItem key={`${element.label}`} value={element.value}>
              {element.label}
            </MenuItem>
          );
        })}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Finally, in the calendar component, use the **calendarRef** in an **useEffect** (*depends on showBy state*) to capture **_calendarAPI.changeView()** method

```js
   React.useEffect(() => {
if (calendarRef.current) {
    calendarRef.current._calendarApi.changeView(showBy);
}
  }, [showBy]);
```